# Is there anybody who can help me in node.js authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

My problem is that, after successful login, the session is being created successfully, but redirect is not working. Why? <br>

[route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Skqa.png)<br>

[form html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6prc.png)

[authenticationcontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTLvk.png)

[login_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiDK6.png)

[core.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Sec.png)

I need your help, thank you.<br>I've tried make some changes in login function and core.js for arrangement, but it didn't work

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)